# Is the implementation of response.info().getencoding() broken in urllib2?

Tags: python, encoding, urllib2

I would expect the output of getencoding in the following python session to be "ISO-8859-1":

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com/")
>>> response.info().plist
['charset=ISO-8859-1']
>>> response.info().getencoding()
'7bit'
```

This is with python version 2.6 ('2.6 (r26:66714, Aug 17 2009, 16:01:07) \n[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5484)]' specifically).

Comment: I would expect to have `charset=UTF-8`.  That's what I get when I inspect the source at google.com.

Comment: As I understand it, this method will only look at the headers and not at the meta tags in the page:

    $ curl -I http://www.google.com/
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Thu, 20 Aug 2009 22:40:54 GMT
    Expires: -1
    Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
    Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=7592ab15eefe9966:TM=1250808054:LM=1250808054:S=KaPYgHdNyGx7eglv; expires=Sat, 20-Aug-2011 22:40:54 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
     Server: gws
     Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Comment: Well I guess comments don't take the same formatting that the posts do, but you get the idea.

Comment: Ok, I just checked too and the meta tags in google's home page for me also reflect ISO-8859-1:

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

Comment: Dug deeper: Hitting google through charles from Firefox it uses utf-8 for both the content-type header and the meta tag, and hitting it through charles from urllib2 in python it uses ISO-8859-1 for both.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what is it you think is broken?

I get ISO-8859-2 for both urllib and wget (I'm currently in Poland). I get UTF-8 with Firefox. This is because my Firefox tells the site it accepts ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8, while wget and urllib2 does not say anything. The relevant request header is:

```
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
```

Remove UTF-8 from that, and you won't get UTF-8, easily testable by telnetting to port 80.

Google.com simply (and reasonably) defaults to ISO-8859-1 and google.pl to ISO-8859-2, and I'm sure there are other defaults for other sites.

I get no encoding header either for wget, urllib2 or telnet, I guess urllib2 then assumes 7bit, and this may be a bit non-sensical, as Content-Encoding typically is either gzip or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the document](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetools.html#mimetools.Message.getencoding)

> Message.getencoding()
>
> Return the encoding specified in the **Content-Transfer-Encoding** message header. If no such header exists, return '7bit'. The encoding is converted to lower case.